# How to draw a circle in Xmgrace

Tags: xmgrace

How to draw a circle in Xmgrace with center in `(x,y)` and diameter `d`? One way is to create sets from two functions. For example, `-(1-x^2)^0.5` and `(1-x^2)^0.5`, but are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

#### Using the GUI

1. In the menu bar, go to `Window > Drawing objects > Ellipse`.
2. Draw any ellipse in the plotting area.
3. Click `Edit object` and select the ellipse.
4. In the new window, change

   - `Position in` to `World Coordinates`.
   - `Xcenter` to the value of `x`.
   - `Ycenter` to the value of `y`.
   - `Width` to `d`.
   - `Height` to `d`.
5. Click `Accept`.

#### From a batch file

Save this `batch.xmg`:

```
WITH ELLIPSE 0
ELLIPSE ON
ELLIPSE LOCTYPE WORLD
ELLIPSE 0,0,1,1
ELLIPSE DEF
```

The `ELLIPSE 0,0,1,1` line defines the `x0,y0,x1,y1` of the circle. So that is a circle centered in `(0.5, 0.5)` and of diameter 1.

Now execute

```
xmgrace -nosafe -batch batch.xmg
```